# Change(toggle) image of a html button on mouse click (in Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a HTML button with image which toggles image in every click. this is the method i use to set the class on each click and according to the current class image is displayed.

```
function FullScreenToggle(el){
    if(el.className!="ns")
    {
        el.className="ns";
    }
    else if(el.className=="ns")
    {
        el.className="fs";
    }
    
return false;

}
```

This works fine on chrome and Firefox, problem here is this doesn't work on IE, even the button do not appear, Its really helpful if someone can give me tip to make this work on IE, Thanks in advance.

### Update

my html

```
 <button class="fullScreen" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" onclick="FullScreenToggle(this);" id="butFullScreen">
                                <input type="image" class="ns" onclick="FullScreenToggle(this);" value="" />
```

CSS

```
.claro #butFullScreen .ns{
    background-image: url("images/fullScreen.png");
}
.claro #butFullScreen .fs{
    background-image: url("images/fullScreenExit.png");
}
```

Comment: show me your html and css

Comment: if this is for full screen, mabye the button doesn't appear because ie doesn't support the fullscreen ?

Comment: @Upvote MarkAnswer I added it as an update, Thanks

Comment: well @fabien thing is button doesn't appear even on normal screen

Comment: Give a name to display for button.Else fix the height and width for that button.Now the thing is button value or text is null.so it wont appear..

Comment: It's often a bad idea to add the javascript like that in the markup. You should do everything in your js file. Do you use any librery (like jquery) to manage the DOM? The "onclick" you use could be something like $("#butFullScreen").click(function(){...}). It would be way more managable.

Comment: Hi, @UpvoteMarkAnswer for these two classes height and width are fixed for 14px. if I put a text there text also appear on the button. so cant afford that.

Comment: Hi @fabien, no choice there, I'm just adding feature o a already running product.

Comment: @Amila: May i know, on which IE is having problem and what is the error?

Comment: @Amila: I have checked in IE10 and checked compatibility view for IE7, IE8, IE9 is working. Hope button image is missing try width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #ccc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anybody wants to know how to do **Fabien's** answer: http://jsfiddle.net/wHkVg/2/

Example of changing background image (untested):

```
// On button click
$('#butFullScreen').click(function() {
    // Change background image
    $(this).css('background-image', url('images/fullScreen.png')); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Jquery, Jquery will be work for all browsers.

Change here :

`FullScreenToggle(this)` to `FullScreenToggle(this.id)`

I am assuming  here parameter is an **id** of element

```
function FullScreenToggle(el)
{
    ($("#"+el).attr('class') != "ns" ) ? $("#"+el).addClass("ns").removeClass('fs') : $("#"+el).addClass("fs").removeClass('ns');
    return false;
}
```

OR

you can use toggle class also

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Let me know is this helpful?.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Type` attribute to first button and close the button element.

```
<button type="button" class="fullScreen" id="butFullScreen">
</button>
```

Hope it helps you.